# OpenLayers 4 - Local Names incorrect in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, openlayers, local, javascript-debugger

I am creating a simple mapping application in Visual Studio 2017. I am using Openlayers v4.6.4 to display the map data and add overlay polygons onto the map.

As OpenLayers 4 is a JS library, I mainly use Internet Explorer as it allows me to add breakpoints in my javascript files on Visual Studio 2017.

I have noticed however that the Local Names of any classes associated with OpenLayers, such as features or geometry, are incorrect and just seem to be random characters.

For example, I have a the following code which is called when a polygon is placed on the map:

```
   //  Event called when the user has finished drawing a polygon/point
    draw.on('drawend', function (e) {

        map.removeInteraction(draw); // Exits drawing mode and enters scroll mode

        var geom = e.feature.getGeometry();
        var format = ol.format.WKT;

        var geomWKT2 = format.writeGeometry(geom);

        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        // Update all client windows with the feature just drawn
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { // Start the connection.
            // Call the Send method on the hub. 
            chat.server.send(geomWKT, 'Luke');
        });
   })
```

However when I view this code in the Visual Studio debugger, the Local Names are only correct up to e.feature, in which afterwards the names become unreadable:

[e.Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sltIL.png)

[geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhfxT.png)

Surely the Local Names in the pictures should have a more accurate description?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ol.js`, which is the minified version. To reduce the file size, variables have been reduced to 1 or 2 letters.

To debug, you should instead use `ol-debug.js`, which is bigger but human readable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was the problem!